# kendo javascript t.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, multi-select

When I try to hide permanently spinning busy indicator of kendo multiselect with telerik function:

```
var multi = $("#statusMultiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect");
kendo.ui.progress(multi, false);
```

I get javascript error:

```
TypeError: t.find is not a function
```

And I have no idea why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didnt manage to find out why I got this error, but at least I know why the busy indicator was spinning.

It took some time to analyse JS and CSS files and apparently some of kendo CSS files were older than they should be and by that incomplete

Comment: This is not an answer. Guy Lowe has the correct answer.

Comment: How can u tell what helped in my own case?

Comment: In that case, your question needs to be closed, because the issue has been caused by a problem that no longer can be reproduced.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and it was because the element I passed to the call was invalid.  Once I changed it to a valid selector it worked.

For example:

```
 kendo.ui.progress($('.myclassselector'), true); //or false to hide it.
```

I suspect the problem in the question was due to passing in a kendo object, not a jquery element as the kendo object won't have this find function where the jquery one will.